# How send email from PHPMAILER without SMTP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Can anyone tell me, how  send email from *PHPMailer* **not** using SMTP? This class includes the method `isMail()` and it should send an email using the `mail()` function instead SMTP. I'm  use Xaamp. When I use SMTP server it's not working all.

**My code:**

```
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->From = 'xxxx@email.com';
$body = "Test body message";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxx@emai.com", "John Doe");
$mail->Subject = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Send Method returns `true` and displays message that email has been sent?

Comment: mail() not working, but i  read, that  PHPMailer uses mail() function too.

Comment: `mail()` relies on their being a properly configured, sendmail-compatible MTA running on the server. If that's not working, then you need to look at the server's logs and config.

Comment: Sometimes the problem isn't with `mail()` function at all. There is just so much spam filtering that your mail just never makes it to the inbox you think it should get to. With XAMPP yes there is some configuration but I'm not sure if that's what's blocking you.

Comment: That code will not send via SMTP - `isMail` is the default, so you don't need to call it. It will submit via the mail() function directly to a local mail server using a sendmail binary. What happens after that will involve SMTP, but it's nothing to do with PHPMailer.

Comment: Hmm, so what I need, to send email without authorization SMTP? simple form contract where client gives your address email and body message.

Answer (score 2):

The topic is old but for those who will read this.
Try to replace

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

by

```
$mail->isSendMail();
```